# Select2 PlugIn Selected value not updated to DropDownList

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-select2

Used Select2 plugin for selecting in dropdown asp.net c#Loaded data to select to using ajax webmethod

CSS : User select2 version Select2-4.0.13 and bootstrap4

```
<link href="Styles/Select2-4.0.13/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Styles/Select2-4.0.13/select2-bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

ASPX  : Created Dropdown list Name with class js-data-example-ajax

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="txtItemName" data-width="100%" CssClass="js-data-example-ajax input-sm w-100"
            AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="txtItemName_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

JAVA SCRIPT : loaded data to select2 dropdown using ajax web method call in document ready section and its loading data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
            ajax: {
                url: 'WebForm1.aspx/getsource',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                delay: 250,
                data: function (params) {

                    var search = '';

                    if (params.term !== undefined) {
                        search = params.term;
                    }

                    return "{'q': '" + search + "'}";
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    var items = JSON.parse(data.d).items

                    if (items == null) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    return {
                        results: items
                    };
                }
            },
            placeholder: 'Search here'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Code Behind : Created Method as web method to load data to dropdown list with select2

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string getsource(string q)
{
    Select2ModelMain obj = new Select2ModelMain();
    obj.items = new List<SelectResult>();

    SelectResult objdata1 = new SelectResult(); objdata1.id = 1; objdata1.text = "INDIA"; obj.items.Add(objdata1);
    objdata1 = new SelectResult(); objdata1.id = 2; objdata1.text = "AMERICA"; obj.items.Add(objdata1);
    objdata1 = new SelectResult(); objdata1.id = 3; objdata1.text = "CHINA"; obj.items.Add(objdata1);
    objdata1 = new SelectResult(); objdata1.id = 4; objdata1.text = "SRILANKA"; obj.items.Add(objdata1);
    obj.pagination = new SelectPage();
    obj.pagination.more = "true";

    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(q) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q)))
    {
        obj.items = obj.items.Where(x => x.text.ToLower().StartsWith(q.ToLower())).ToList();
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string test = serializer.Serialize(obj);
    return test;
}
public class Select2ModelMain
{
    public List<SelectResult> items { get; set; }
    public SelectPage pagination { get; set; }
}

public class SelectResult
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string disabled { get; set; }
}

public class SelectPage
{
    public string more { get; set; }
}
```

Initially we are getting error like :

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
> using

so we added "enableEventValidation="false" " in @page section

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" enableEventValidation="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
```

Next :  SelectedIndexChanged event was not firing

so added line `<asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>` under dropdownlist

but select2 is not updating selected item to dropdownlist we are getting empty string in selected text and value field refer Image 1

[refer Image Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCY5Z.png)

[selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhGjt.png)